# forever restarts every 8 hours?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever, forever-monitor

I am using node with forever for the first time. In log file I am finding that my server is getting restarted every 8 hours. Is it because of any forever module option? Can't it run without restarting except when the code breaks? Please suggest.

Comment: I don't think it's because of forever. but you can try something like `pm2`?

Comment: May I know what do you guess would be the issue @TuanAnhTran

Comment: it would help if you can provide the log here so other can take a look and guess.

Comment: Please find the logs: {"level":"info","message":"Response sent to the client : {\"getResp\":{\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"description\":\"Success\"},\"specificDetails\":[{}]}}","timestamp":"2015-10-29T10:35:06.409Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"Response from the server complete..","timestamp":"2015-10-29T10:35:06.409Z"}
{"level":"info","message":"Server has started.","timestamp":"2015-10-29T14:30:29.860Z"}
{"level":"error","message":"Error in connecting to mySql : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED","timestamp":"2015-10-29T14:30:29.900Z"}